# How to add expiry time in hours for a cookie in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, cookies, angular2-cookie

How to add expiry time in hours for a cookie, I am able to do with days.

```
Cookie.set('SESSION_TOKEN', sessionToken, 6); // here 6 is days
```

I want in hours. I want cookie to be expired in 6 hours.

```
Cookie.set('SESSION_TOKEN', sessionToken, 6(hours)); // 6 hours
```

Below is the code I am using, but I am getting an error "*Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'*"

```
setCookie(userObject) {
    let expire = new Date();
    var time = Date.now() + ((3600 * 1000) * 6);
    expire.setTime(time);
    console.log("expire "+expire);
    Cookie.set('USER_NAME',Base64.encode(userObject.user.email),expire);
    Cookie.set('SESSION_TOKEN',userObject.sessionToken,expire);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using `angular2-cookie` and not `ng2-cookies`? Cause I couldn't find any `set` method in angula2-cookie API.  The only way you can set a cookie in the current version is `put(key: string, value: string, options?: CookieOptionsArgs): void;`

Comment: can you try setting the second parameter of the 'set' method to empty string (``Cookie.set('test','', expire)``) and tell me what output you get? Also do you get this error while transpiling your ts code to js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had done like this, it worked for me.

```
 Cookie.set('SESSION_TOKEN',userObject.sessionToken,0.25);
```

Actually if we give `1` it stays long for 24hrs, So I applied mathematical logic to it, i.e. for 6 hours.

```
1 day -> 24 hrs
? day -> 6 hrs
(1*6)/24 -> 0.25 i.e. 6hrs
```

Comment: I ran into the type mismatch although the code in the library seems to handle dates just fine, and passing fractions is a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the current version of `ng2-cookies` doesn't contain such a feature which would allow you to define hours instead of days. Therefore you have to manually calculate the time when the cookie will expire.

[ng2-cookies/src/cookie.ts](https://github.com/BCJTI/ng2-cookies/blob/master/src/cookie.ts)

```
/**
 * Save the Cookie
 *
 * @param  {string} name Cookie's identification
 * @param  {string} value Cookie's value
 * @param  {number} expires Cookie's expiration date in days from now or at a specific date from a Date object. If it's undefined the cookie is a session Cookie
 * @param  {string} path Path relative to the domain where the cookie should be avaiable. Default /
 * @param  {string} domain Domain where the cookie should be avaiable. Default current domain
 * @param  {boolean} secure If true, the cookie will only be available through a secured connection
 */
public static set(name: string, value: string, expires?: number | Date, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean) {
```

So I suppose something like this may work.

```
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies';

var expire = new Date();
var time = Date.now() + ((3600 * 1000) * 6); // current time + 6 hours ///
expire.setTime(time);

Cookie.set("test", "", expire);
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'" at Cookie.set('SESSION_TOKEN',sessionToken, expire);

Comment: are you using the latest version (`ng2-cookies@1.0.4` ) ? Cuase I just tried it and it's working. (also updated my answer with a short example)

Comment: Yes, I am doing the latest version of ng2-cookies i.e.("ng2-cookies": "^1.0.4"). No change, getting same error **Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'**

Comment: can you please update your question above with a short example? I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: I have added my code. Please check it once. And mention me the changes to be done.
**note:** I am using angular2

Comment: I'd recommend checking the `ng2-cookies` package manually. Go to your the `node_modules/ng2-cookies/src/cookie.ts` and see how are the parameters defined for  'set' method. Or better do the `npm cache clean` and reinstall the packages.

Comment: I have done, but no change in it. @Alexus if you see the params, there is no 'Date' variable. That is the reason why I am not getting. So I tried with different method, I just posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like below and set it in hours for less complexity:

```
const now = new Date();
now.setHours(now.getHours() + 8);
Cookie.set('SESSION_TOKEN', sessionToken, now);
```

Then you can set your preferable expiration time in hours easily by changing the number in `setHours` :)